# Loop returns false after random number of iteration in python

Tags: python, list

In the below code

```
import pyzipcode as pyzip
location = []
for var in grouped_list_long_zip:
    holder = pyzip.Pyzipcode.get(var[0][4], 'US', return_json=False)
    location.append(holder['location'])
```

`grouped_list_long_zip` is a list of list of list which contains locations where the fourth index in each sublist is the zipcode. Using this and the module `pyzipcode`, I want to return latitude and longitude location of the zipcodes and store them in `location`. My problem is after a random number of iteration the function will return `false` and make `holder` a `bool` type. The most common iteration it fails on is the 11th, but it also happens on other iterations. I am unsure of how to debug this problem.

Edit:

When the code fails `var` simply equals what `grouped_lsit_long_zip` equals at that location.

Comment: judging from the `var[0][4]` in conjunction with `for var in grouped_list_long_zip`, grouped_list_long_zip seems to be a list of lists of lists ( [[[]]] )

Comment: is `holder` a dictionary? Which function returns `False`?

Comment: the function `pyzip.Pyzipcode.get` returns a dictionary so `holder` gets declared as a dictionary each time. I'm also assuming that `pyzip.Pyzipcode.get` is what returns false, however, what is strange is that if I simply do `print(pyzip.Pyzipcode.get(pyzip.Pyzipcode.get(var[0][4], 'US', return_json=False)` at the location it fails I do not get this error.

Comment: Of course `var` equals what `grouped_lsit_long_zip` at that location. Thats what the `for` does. This happens on all iterations, not just the *weird* one. I would suggest going through the `pyzipcode` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I would modify the code like that to get some feedback on the values that *disrupt the execution*.

```
import pyzipcode as pyzip
location = []

for var in grouped_list_long_zip:
    holder = pyzip.Pyzipcode.get(var[0][4], 'US', return_json=False)
    if type(holder) == bool:
        print(var[0])
    else:
        location.append(holder['location'])
```

Another thing you can do is wrapping the thing in a `try-except` block to simply ignore the problematic cases if an error is thrown.

Comment: It equals what `grouped_list_long_zip` is in the same location. I updated the question to state that and you are correct about it being a list of list of list.

Comment: @Jstuff so there is nothing special about the value of `var[0][4]` when the `holder` suddenly becomes of type `bool`?